# Как в activity отображать данные из выбранной категории?

Tags: java, android, realm

У меня есть база с тремя таблицами: Категория, подкатегория и товар. При нажатии на подкатегорию, должны открыться товары именно выбранной подкатегории.
В самом начале я с сервера делаю парсинг JSON'a, в котором есть все категории, подкатегории, товары и ложу их в каждый отдельный массив. Потом я их все загоняю в локальную базу Realm и вывожу все категории в `RecyclerView` при помощи метода:

```
realm.where(Category.class).equalTo(status, 1).findAll();
```

Минус такого подхода в том, что он выводит все подкатегории где в поле status стоит 1, а это значит мне придется вручную везде проставлять значения status, но для подкатегорий это подойдет, потому что категорий(родитель) всего 2 штуки, а вот подкатегорий будет очень много, соответственно вручную всё это хардкодить будет проблемно и глупо.

Как это реализовать? Надеюсь понятно объяснил ситуацию, если нет - пишите в комментарии что нужно уточнить, я отредактирую вопрос.
Я использую Realm, Retrofit 2.

Comment: Realm сам [умеет парсить](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json) JSON ([пример](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/jsonExample/src/main)). Ничего лучшего кроме того, как устанавливать подкатегориям идентификаторы и по ним делать выборку как то не придумали, почему вы считаете, что это глупо и проблемно

Comment: например: Array List categories = realm.where(Category.class).equalTo(idCategory, 1).findAll(); - Если я сделаю так, то если я захочу создать из админки новую категорию, то мне придётся лезть в код и создавать там новый id и прописывать этот метод ream.where

Comment: очень негибко получается если нужно будет удалять, создавать новые категории

Comment: В код не надо лезть. Обычно категории выводятся каким то списком, нажатие на пункт списка имеет его позицию в этом списке (или при нажатии пункта получаем его ID). Затем эта позиция (или ID) используется в запросе (подставляется в запрос динамически, а не прописаны хардкорные запросы). Да, вы добавляете новую категорию в БД, присваиваете ей ID и помечаете этим ID все относящееся к этой категории, но в код никаких изменений не вносится при этом - один и тот же запрос получает выборку по любому ID. Если вас "парит", что нужно набирать большой объем данных в БД, то вы не ту профессию выбрали.

Comment: Например: при нажатии на пункт получили его ID и присвоили переменной - `id = 1`, вызываем метод-запрос к БД, передавая туда аргументом полученный ID и возвращая из метода результат выборки - `ArrayList categories = realm.where(Category.class).equalTo(idCategory, id).findAll();` Получим все, связанное с категорией с ID = 1, отправив туда 2 - получим все по второй категории и тд